# Adding App Recommendation Support Library for TV

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-tv

I am trying to add the app recommendation surrport library for TV to my Android TV project, but when I add the following Gradle dependency, it fails to find it:

```
compile 'com.android.support:app.recommendation-app:23.0.0'
```

I have the Android Support Repository downloaded via the SDK Manager, but it cannot seem to resolve the dependency.

Here is the link to the Android documentation: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#recommendation

Comment: Looks like perhaps they have not released that part yet. I don't see it in my repo either, though most if not all of the other new ones are there.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yeah, same thing for me. Looks like someone had a copy/paste problem on that page. It says that the library is located here: `<sdk>/extras/android/support/customtabs`. Same with the percent support library...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the library is now included in the release of the `23.0.1` revision of the Android Support Library. It can be added as a dependency to a project like this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recommendation:23.0.1'
```